# Is there a (reasonably easy) way to run word usage statistics on a document?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2011

I have a rather lengthy Word document file.  I would like to run an analytical report on this document that summarizes the most common words and provides a count of how often each word appears.

Does such a tool exist within Word?  I'd prefer an integrated solution, even if it requires a little VBA (shudder).  Is this possible?

I have Office 2011:Mac installed on my machine as well as Office 2010 for Windows (via parallels.)  I'd prefer an answer specific to the Mac version, but if my only option is for the Windows version, that is acceptable.

Comment: Look at the Bullfighter addin for word. It may provide enough functionality for what you want. It is my favorite word addin anyway just to analyze some of the crap that I get from vendors. :)

Comment: @EBGreen, do you have a link?  The only version of BullFighter that I can find is for office 2000 and XP.  I'm using 2010 or 2011:Mac.

Comment: Oretty sure that I use the 2000 version in 2010.\

Comment: I tried to use it, bit states that it's an incompatible add-in.  Odd.

Comment: Unless you are doing this on many many words just go with good ol CTRL + F.  Ill give you a count and a snippet of where it came from...

Answer (score 1):

You could try to copy the contents of the document and then run

```
pbpaste|tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'|grep -Eo "[[:alpha:]'-]+"|sort|uniq -c|sort -n
```

in Terminal.

Comment: Before normalizing case, you could split camel case words and and those with digits:
`echo 'hello camelCase, hiThere version2.1' | sed 's/\([a-z]\)\([A-Z0-9]\)/\1 \2/g'` hello camel Case, hi There version 2.1

Comment: I just applied the following in a Cygwin terminal: `cat <filename> | grep -Eo "[[:alpha:]'-]+"|sort|uniq -c|sort -n`, it is doing exactly what I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.wordcounter.com/

Here's a place on the web that does easy word stats.   Just paste into the box and click.